# callbacks order in rails 3 when using inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, callback

I'd like to know the order in which the callback functions are executed in `rails 3` when using inheritance..

To make my question clearer, here is an example from [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

we have a parent class

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :destroy_author
end
```

and a child class

```
class Reply < Topic
  before_destroy :destroy_readers
end
```

and both have callbacks on before_destroy.
So, which of them is executed first??

Comment: Your parent and child class are almost identical is this a mistake?

Comment: @Steve you are right, I just ctrl+c ctrl+v it
I'll fix it rightaway

Answer (score 2):

all parent callbacks called before child callbacks

on rails 3 callbacks:
http://intridea.com/posts/define-custom-callbacks-for-activerecord-and-more

Comment: That's what I'm seeing. Does that make sense? Shouldn't the execution traverse the hierarchy from most specific (child) to base class?

Comment: Is there a way we can make the parent callback be always called in last?

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :destroy_author, `append: true`
end

Something like this?